# Ixxat CAN@net NT 200: What is the maximum number of configurable messages filters the Generic protocol allows?

Tags: api, tcp, ascii, iot, can-bus

The title already contains everything.

(I am using "Generic Protocol 2.1 for Gateway Mode V6".)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from the Ixxat technical support:

For 11 bit message identifiers:

- all 2048 Identifiers on every CAN (mask / value will converted
  internal to ID table)

For 29 bit message identifiers:

- 8 real mask/value filter on every CAN port, and
- a hash filter for 256 single identifiers on every CAN

Remark: All settings with the mask = 0x1FFFFFFF will be added to the hash filter, otherwise a mask/value filter will be used.